# symmetric polynomials in functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

If I have $N$ variables, $a_i$, $i=1,...,N$, then any symmetric polynomial in these can be expressed as a polynomial in the elementary symmetric polynomials:

$$ e_k = \sum_{i_1<...<i_k} a_{i_1} ...a_{i_k}, \;\;\; k=1,...,N $$

Now suppose I instead have $N$ functions, $f_i(x)$, $i=1,...,N$.  Now I'm interested in symmetric polynomials in the functions, which may be evaluated at different arguments, eg, something like (for $N=2$):

$$ {f_1(x)}^2 f_2(y) + {f_2(x)}^2 f_1(y) $$

Is there some analogous set of ``generating functions'' for these symmetric polynomials?  Perhaps it is natural to define

$$ e_k(x_1,...x_k) = f_{1}(x_1) ...f_{k}(x_k) + \text{permutations}, \;\;\; k=1,...,N $$
which I may take arbitrary polynomials in and evaluate at arbitrary arguments.  But I'm not sure this is enough to capture everything.

Comment: Could you give some more examples, or try to give a more precise formulation of what kind of polynomials you want to consider? Is it just arbitrary, which argument is put into which function? So would $f_1(x)^2f_2(y) + f_2(y)^2f_1(x)$ also be a valid term?

Comment: What I had in mind was that the function should  be symmetric under arbitrary permutations of the labels, in this case, {1,2}->{2,1}, so your example would not satisfy this.  What I'm really interested in the specific case of functions of the form $\sum_{i=1}^N f_i(x_1)^{k_1} f_i(x_2)^{k_2} ...$, which are analogous to power sums in the usual case, and expressing these in terms of some finite generating set, but I'm not sure this is possible.